# Lights looking weird

Tags: rendering, light, eevee-render-engine

I add light but what ı do its looks still pixel

https://pasteboard.co/IH6dcFq.png I render with eevee.

Why it's happening.

https://pasteboard.co/IH7xBME.png These my nodes for wooden table.

Comment: Please show the table's material node tree

Comment: I add my nodes with edit post.

Answer (score 0):

If your problem is that the light is too small, then changing the radius setting in the properties should fix your problem. If it is too weak, you should change the power setting.
[image: Where to change the settings]

If that doesn't answer your question, please specify.

Comment: I think problem happening from wood table in scene because when i change color ramp (connected roughness) it's decrease little bit not completely.

Answer (score 0):

-Low Texture Resolution / Light with Specular = 1

-High Texture Resolution / Light With Specular = 1

-High Texture Resolution / Light with Specular = 0

see if tweaking any of these values solvesyour problem

[image]

Comment: If ı change specular then lights being not enough for scene but probly this was a bug because i render with cycle everythings be perfect. Lightning still not good but thats my failure.

Comment: hummm, try this with 2.81 to see if its still an issue